# Programmatically change Fab design support library size?

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I cannot find how to change the size of the Fab programmatically, is this not possible? I looked through the documentation and I could not find anything.

Comment: There's no exposed API for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have my FAB set up in the following manner:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add_large"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_background"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/fab_anim"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_add"/>
```

From here you can get the `ImageButton` via the id in your Java code and then change the `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

As far as the values and other resources related to FAB goes, there is sample code in your SDK folder that you can look at. That is where I got my code from.

However I would look to the documentation on the FAB first, there are only 2 sizes that it "should" be. Default, and mini:

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button